# How to calculate image height dynamically at hover effect in CSS?

Tags: css, css-animations

My need is to **calculate** an **image** **height value dynamically** at the **hover effect** when using transform: translateY( ). As I did at hove I use `transform: translateY( -80% )` this **-80%** value needs to come **dynamically** from **images height** according to those individual images & of course, these images heights are different from each other, (*in short, all images heights are not the same*).

So instead of using this static -80% hard-coded value, want to use **variable images height** at **hover effect** to respect those individual images height.

```
.image {
    height    : 30rem;
    width     : 40rem;
    overflow  : hidden;
}

.image:hover  img {
    transform : translateY(-80%); 
   /* this -80% value should be dynamic, base on img height value */
}

img {
    width     : 100%;
    transition: 5s ease;
}
```

Comment: Either ensure all images are same height (with CSS) or use JS to calculate it, CSS does not have resource inspection features

Comment: Please make a minimum example snippet we can run here, translate is already relative to the height of the element in question, I'm struggling to understand what you want to achieve